# Clickatell tells that SMS a successfully sent to gateway but messages are not delivered

Tags: clickatell

I'm trying to establish SMS sending with Node.js via Clickatell.

I've already tried the way described here: https://www.clickatell.com/developers/api-documentation/nodejs/

And both REST and HTTP requests from here (topics "How do I test my HTTP integration?" and "How do I test my REST API integration?"): https://www.clickatell.com/faqs/product-specific-faqs/platform/integration-testing/

In "SMS integration" area for both HTTP and REST APIs delivery type been set to: "Time critical delivery".

And i'm sending messages to number, that is in "test phones" list.

All the messages, I've sent to the server, are visible in "Reporting" area. But all them are stuck in "Delivered_to_gateway" status.

What i'm doing wrong?

**UPD**:

So, first message is finaly delivered to cell phone. After almost one and half hour of waiting.

I've also tried to send message to another phone with another cell operator ("Mobile network: Beeline (KB Impuls, VimpelCom)"), and it delivered in a minute or two.

So, **detailing my question**: it seems Clickatell have some kind of problems with delivering messages to "Mobile network: MTS (Sistema, Prim Telefon)". Can it be fixed somehow?

Comment: Is it only on the free testing plan or it's always like that?

Comment: Same problem here for a Swiss mobile provider